# Не могу осуществить звонок CALL_PHONE

Tags: android, permissions

Нашел код в форуме, по которому вроде должно все работать. После нажатия в консоле выводится *Exception*. Подскажите как правильно обработать кнопку.

В манифете прописал  :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

В адаптере :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentWelcom.call(position);
        }
    });
```

Во фрагменте:

```
public void call(final int position) {
    try {
        int number = 23;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stacktrace :

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err:     at com.cholak.v3.appPineapple.fragments.FragmentWelcom.call(FragmentWelcom.java:197)
W/System.err:     at com.cholak.v3.appPineapple.adapter.RecyclerAdapter$3.onClick(RecyclerAdapter.java:85)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4295)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17456)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: в `catch` добавьте строчку `e.printStackTrace();` и приложите stacktrace в вопрос

Comment: ну соответственно это значение `contactsList.get(position).getPrice()` у вас `null` ищите ошибку

Comment: Может это и не существенно (я не тестировал), но в коде, который использую я, используется паттерн `tel:/`. Если после исправления `NullPointerException` все ещё не будет работать - попробуйте изменить паттерн

Comment: Я сделал int переменную number, и записал туда число, вместо contactsList.get(position).getPrice() Теперь та же ошибка в строке ' startActivity(intent); '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для адекватной работы метода `startActivity()` его нужно вызывать из `Activity`, а не из `Fragment`. Замените строку `startActivity(intent)` на `getActivity().startActivity(intent)`

Comment: не помогло, ошибка та самая.

Comment: Можно весь листинг ошибки?

Comment: @Fedia А вы уверены что экземпляр фрагмента (переменная `fragmentWelcom`) в адаптере не равен `null`?

Comment: Да (переменная `fragmentWelcom`) была инициализирована. ( `fragmentWelcom = new FragmentWelcom();`)

Comment: Вы еще здесь ? Вы мне поможете ?

Comment: @Fedia Вам необходимо не инициализировать её новым фрагментом, а передать уже существующий (из которого мы создаём адаптер)